# Plone visual editor missing now

Tags: tinymce, plone

Running Plone 4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 desktop.  The tinymce editor is no longer available.  I've tried preferences with no luck.  I've read this thread [Missing TinyMCE on a Diazo themed Plone site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561346/missing-tinymce-on-a-diazo-themed-plone-site) but can't even find portal_skins/properties in my setup.  The editor was showing up a few days ago and now no dice.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Has the site had an upgrade? In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095303/plone-4-3-default-editor-isnt-showing-up SteveM has several suggestions, probably importing upgrade-steps can help.

Comment: Any JavaScript error from debug console? Also, screenshots of your editing page might be helpful to identify your issue.

Comment: This happens a lot, and i haven't seen a satisfactory pattern to reproduce/bugfix for it as yet unfortunately.